# How to link Eclipse to YouWave?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, emulation

[YouWave](http://youwave.com/) is a faster Android emulator than the Android emulator from Android SDK. Can I link Eclipse to YouWave, so that when I run programs in Eclipse, YouWave automatically runs that project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try entering this line in your command shell. It worked fine for me.

**adb connect localhost:5558**

It is gradually in the format--->> **adb connect [your ip]:port number**

**Default port is 5555** for adb and 5555-5557 are reserved for some purpose.

So Here 5558 is the port number that is used.

If you're having any confusion regarding the ip address of your machine, simply write 'localhost'.

Hope this helps,

Sid

Answer (score 1):

If I am not mistaken you cannot do that currently. They have it on their list of things to do but they haven't done it yet as far as I know.

http://youwave.com/forum/index.php?topic=1942.0

What you can do is the following: 
"you can write a script to copy your APK files to a directory and use YouWave to run it"

You can look at this post in YouWave.com for more details:

https://youwave.com/forum/index.php?topic=71.0

Comment: Oh, i can link my app from bin folder in my project to start my app.. Thanks!